# Using BGInfo for a specific User

Tags: windows-7

I have a question. I've seen this article ([Run BGInfo At Startup For All Users](https://serverfault.com/questions/451791/run-bginfo-at-startup-for-all-users)on) how to get it to run for all users on a computer. How can I get it to run on a computer for a specific user (say a visitor/guest account).

I want it to only run local on a per machine basis without using a script.

Example, Computer A has 3 local users (Jim, Jill, Guest). I only want GUEST to launchi BGINFO, but not for Jim and Jill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The not so elegant answer that meets your "without using a script" requirement is to create a shortcut pointing to your bginfo config files, and just throw it in that users startup folder.

Here is an example of what those paths inside the shortcut would look like, calling bginfo.exe and feeding it a config file named config.bgi

- Create new shortcut,
- Target: C:\Utilities\bginfo\Bginfo.exe "C:\Utilities\bginfo\config.bgi" /nolicprompt /timer:00
- Start In: C:\Utilities\bginfo\

Their startup folder will have path similiar to this (Win7).

- C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Where %USERNAME% is the name of the user.

You could also create a Scheduled Task using that same command in the "Target" section of the shortcut from above to run for that specific user at logon.  This is probably a better idea given the user could just delete the shortcut in their startup folder.

- Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler
- Create Task
- On the Triggers" tab click "New"

  - Select "At Log on" from the drop down list at the top.
  - Select the "Specific user:" bullet below that, and enter in the username you want it to run under.
- On the "Actions" tab click "New..."

  - Select "Start a program" from the drop down list.
  - Under "Program/script:" enter your path to bginfo.exe (Ex: C:\Utilities\bginfo\Bginfo.exe)
  - Next to "Add arguments (Optional):" you would enter the path to the config file, and other options.  (Ex. "C:\Utilities\bginfo\config.bgi" /nolicprompt /timer:00)

I'd always go the Task Scheduler route personally.  Cool thing about task scheduler is you can export the template as an XML file and then just import it with a little tweak for other users when needed, saving yourself some time.  :)

Comment: I completely forgot about Task Scheduler. I will try that out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the "Startup" folder in the Startmenu